# sql join string match

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, inner-join, contains

lets say i have 2 tables

```
ID      Product
----------------
 micrsoft sql 
 cisco 


ID      Product
----------------
sql
cisco agent
flash
```

I need to write a query that returns only 'flash' as output becasue it does not have a match on table 1. The words cisco and microsoft have matches on the other table and so needs to be discarded.

This is more of an inner join but using pattern/string match/contains. The strings needs not be an absolute match and can also be a subset . for eg. you have cisco in one table and cisco agent in the other .

/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/

```
SELECT  
      [Product] 
  FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2

ON t1.Product= t2.Product
order BY Product
```

will only satisy those products whose value exactly match . But i would need to query even partial matches

Answer (score 1):

You can use `like` for this purpose:

```
SELECT t2.[Product] 
FROM t2 LEFT JOIN
     t1
     ON t1.Product LIKE '%' + t2.Product + '%' OR
        t2.Product LIKE '%' + t1.Product + '%'
WHERE t1.Product IS NULL
ORDER BY t2.Product;
```

Performance will not be good, so I hope you don't have too much data.

Comment: have about 200,000 rows

Comment: why have you added "t1.product is null"?

Comment: To get the rows that do not have a match, as your question states.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select Id, Product
from table2 t2
where ID Not IN ( Select IDFrom table1 )
```